# CleanUp Desktop Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, group-policy

I am searching for a Windows setting (GPO?), scheduled task or a tiny script that enables me either to prevent users to save anything to the Windows desktop or to clean up the entire desktop (shortcuts, files, folders) in a predefined time interval.

The only "hack" I found so far is to restrict user permissions on the desktop folder.

Isn't there a more general solution for clean-up tasks like this?

Comment: whats the problem with `del /q /f %userprofile%\Desktop\*` ?

Comment: Ouch... Well, that looks promising. I will give that a try in combination with a scheduled task. I will let you know if it worked... Thanks so far...

Comment: More importantly: *why* would you want to do that? User desktops are by design user-writable. I don't know about anyone else, but I would be really pissed if someone decided to delete things from my desktop that I put there.

Comment: The workstations are used for training purposes. We want to make sure that the desktop is always clean for the upcomping course participant.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. But finally I used the solution suggsted by Mofi (deleting also the sbfolders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I agree with [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers): Why delete files and folders of users desktop?

I know, there are some use cases where this makes sense. But such an intervention in the user management should be really explained when asking here on Stack Overflow such a question.

Second, the delete command posted by [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) just deletes all files in users desktop folder, but not the subfolders in desktop folder.

Therefore a batch file would need one more line:

```
@echo off
del /F /Q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*" 2>nul
for /D %%D in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*") do rd /Q /S "%%~D" 2>nul
```

After this operation just the items from all users desktop folder are still displayed on desktop of the user.

To prevent users to put files and folders on their own desktop, the string value `Desktop` in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
```

and in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

could be modified to all users desktop folder which is by default write-protected via appropriate NTFS permissions for standard users.

Of course also the NTFS permissions of folder `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` could be changed after the cleanup to prevent a user to put files and folders on own desktop.